# Can I somehow use JHipster Microservice application with DB2

Tags: hibernate, db2, jhipster, microservices

My application would mostly depend on already running stored procedures. I may do hibernate or native jdbc calls to DB2 from microservices. Is there a way to use DB2 database (cause I can not change the database)?

I may also accept generation of the microservices, gateways in jhipster and changing db configuration manually for DB2 as answer or anything similar which allows automatic code generation with jhipster and benefiting from gateway, service registry and load balancing.

May be I can configure a second db for Jhipster configuration? and use DB2 for data only??

I need quick answer on this subject.

Regards,
Ferda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JHipster does not support DB2 but you can modify generated code and datasource definition, Liquibase supports DB2, so it's probably a reasonable work as long as you are fluent in Spring Boot, JPA and Hibernate.

Doing this manually after code generation will probably makes it harder for you to run `jhipster upgrade` so an alternative would be [to create a JHipster module](http://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-module/) or a [blueprint](https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-blueprint/).

I don't think that microservices would help here as it's the same code generation that would be impacted.

Comment: Thank you Gael. That's a big relief for me. Changing datasource manually is no problem. I don't think a frequent upgrade is required for this organization in terms of JHipster version. Previous software (which will be replaced) is implemented 10 years ago with no technology upgrade. I structured whole my solution with JHipster and last night I learnt that Jhipster enterprise Edition (supporting DB2 ) published on JHipster site was a april first joke :)

Comment: :) Microservices could help by implementing strangler pattern around your legacy app though this is hard to design your domain model this way.

Comment: Hi Gael, can you please upvote the question. I have issues related to the number of questions with 0 votes. This problem causes me not entering new questions